# Twitter Widget won't let me change the URL

Tags: javascript, twitter, widget

I have embedded the twitter widget in an HTML. I have a JS object that contains URLs of 10 twitter profiles. I want to make a function that would let me replace the current URL (in the widget) with another one from the object.
However when running the script, the href will not change (error say its null).

Does Twitter maybe prevent any changes to href or other tags inside the HTML class?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <p>
    <a class="twitter-timeline" id="twitter" data-width="300" data-height="500" href="https://twitter.com/Tesla"></a>
  </p>

  <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

  <button onclick="change()">Change link</button> <button onclick="check()">Preview link</button>

  <script>
    var URL = document.getElementById("twitter").href;
    console.log(URL);

    function change() {
      alert(document.getElementById("twitter").href = "https://twitter.com/IBMref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor");
    }

    function check() {
      console.log(document.getElementById("twitter").href);
    }
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Cannot replicate this Null Error.

Answer (score 0):

It did change, you just called alert on the change itself.

```js
var URL = document.getElementById("twitter").href;
console.log(URL);

function change() {
  document.getElementById("twitter").href = "https://twitter.com/IBM?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor";
  alert(document.getElementById("twitter").href);
}

function check() {
  console.log(document.getElementById("twitter").href);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    <a class="twitter-timeline" id="twitter" data-width="300" data-height="500" href="https://twitter.com/Tesla"></a>
  </p>
  <button onclick="change()">Change link</button>
  <button onclick="check()">Preview link</button>
</body>

</html>
```